# How to find DotNetNuke pages that point to my dnn page

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I have updated an existing user DNN page with some text. I can preview this page using the Page Management page. Since I didn't create this page I don't know which other pages/menus contain a link to this page. How can I find out which pages/menus link to this page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Who or what created the page?

What is the URL that you visit to edit the page? (Edit the URL here to use a phony name.)

Comment: The page is user created.  I already existed when I started working on this.  I can see the page as Admin in the Page Administration tree. The page only contains text...the URL is something like this: 

https://www.mycompany.com/terms-conditions/online-payments

Answer (score 0):

Getting the exact number of links to a page is almost impossible without the use of a site crawler, as the page could be referenced in many ways.

- Via HTML Content on a Page - This would be in the HTMLText table of the database
- Via a Page-Link Menu Item - This would be in the Tabs table of the database
- Via a URL-Link Menu Item - This would be in the Tabs table as well, just tied by the URL rather than the TabId

There is no report/link in the DNN Platform to list all usages.